# How to specify tablespace_name in SQLPlus Oracle select

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

My setup looks like this

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name, table_name
     FROM all_tables
     WHERE tablespace_name = 'MYSPACE';

TABLESPACE_NAME            TABLE_NAME
-------------------------- ------------------------------
MYSPACE                    MYTABLENAME
MYSPACE                    MYOTHERTABLENAME
```

Now I'd like to `SELECT * FROM MYSPACE.MYTABLENAME;` but that's apparently not how you do it.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

My expected result would be to get all records from that table. Like I would if it was MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected result from the 2nd query? I mean what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I think what you want is to select the owner and table_name from all_tables, and then `select * from owner.tablename` query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are selecting from tablespace, which is not the same as your Owner/Schema name. Thats  why. For example the tablespace `SYSTEM` has owner `SYS`. You do select from Sys.xxx;

Ok.

```
SELECT owner, tablespace_name, table_name
FROM all_tables
WHERE tablespace_name = 'MYSPACE';
```

And then

```
select * from [ owner ].[ table_name ];
```

(worth to mention: select .. from `dba_tables` / `user_tables`)

Answer (score 4):

Tables are not owned by a tablespace. A tablespace is [a logical storage storage structure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT301). When you create a table (or index) you specify which tablespace its contents should be [stored in](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1128). Unless you're doing DBA tasks, you don't really need to know which tablespace(s) your data is stored in.

You may just be confusing terms. Tables are owned by [schemas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT111). If you query the `owner` column instead of `tablespace_name` you might see something like:

```
SQL> SELECT owner, table_name
     FROM all_tables
     WHERE tablespace_name = 'MYSPACE';

OWNER                      TABLE_NAME
-------------------------- ------------------------------
MYUSER                     MYTABLENAME
MYUSER                     MYOTHERTABLENAME
```

And you can then query from that with

```
SELECT * FROM MYOWNER.MYTABLENAME;
```

Of course, if the owner is actually you anyway, then you don't need to prefix the table name with the schema; you can just select `FROM MYTABLENAME`. (You may also have synonyms or session settings that make the schema prefix unnecessary, but that's getting a a bit off-topic). And if you own the table you'll see it in `USER_TABLES` as well.